# CodeIgniter URI Routing is not working as expected

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

There are something in the user guide like this

```
(:num) will match a segment containing only numbers.
```

so I do this

```
//using wildcard
$route['tool/reply/(\d+)'] = "tool/reply/$1";
//or using regx like this
//$route['tool/reply/(:num)'] = "tool/reply/$1";
```

But it not only matches numeric numbers, it matches strings as well. What happened? Did I miss something?

Comment: come on, guys. really need some help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having your function `tool/reply` to something like `tool/reply_numeric`. It could be getting confused and just be routing to your controller and skipping your routes.

Comment: u didn't get my point, what I mean is that the wildcard is not working, it should match numeric number only, but it matches character as well.

Comment: if I set $route['tool/reply/(\d+)'] = "tool/reply/$1"; then tool/reply/123 will match, tool/reply/asdf will not match, but now it matches both of them, do u know why?

Comment: Yes, re-read my answer again. Change your function `reply()` to `reply_numeric()`. CodeIgniter is most likely ignoring your routes because you have the controller defining that route already.

Comment: I am sorry, I just edited my question, please take a look again

Comment: You still haven't grasped what I'm telling you. Your controller in `application/controller/tool.php` is defining `function reply($input)` which accepts all inputs and is ignoring your routes file definition. You need to modify your function definition to `reply_numeric($input)` so that your route turns out to be `$route['tool/reply/(:num)'] = "tool/reply_numeric/$1";`

Comment: thank you very much. but I still wonder it's mentioned in the doc that the re-mapped URI can't be as same as the orignal one

Comment: I'll investigate it more, see if I can make that contribution for you